# .Net - Win 7 64 Code Security

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-7, cas

Our company is in the process of upgrading to windows 7 64-bit. Some of our .net 3.5 apps that ran fine under XP are now trowing security errors for untrusted assemblies. Our new machines have .net 4 installed. Do I need to also install 3.5 SP1 on the new machines? Is CASPOL.exe still the tool to use to resolve these issues? Is digitally signing apps the way to go? I'm confused in general on how the new security stuff works with .net and 64 bit Win 7. I'm not finding a lot of good info on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You normally should not have to sign any DLLs, unless you want them to interact with some application which requires them to be signed, or to safely install them on another computer. Signing them should not hurt.

I would doubt this is a 64-bit specific issue, but most likely rather a .NET 4 and increased security issue coming from Microsoft, or a configuration issue.